# Single page web application refresh button Get not supported

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, spring-mvc

I am using angularjs and spring mvc to build an Application, I have written rest api, which will get data from back end and i am displaying it using angularjs ng-grid. My question is when i click on refresh button i am getting response as **HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'GET' not supported** what is the reason i am getting this response ? and how to solve this ?

is there any way if i click on refresh button of browser it should point to landing page of my application.

**Angular js controller code**

```
function customerController($scope,$http,$window,$location,updateFactory) {

$scope.customerId;
$scope.customerEmail;
$scope.CustName;


$http.get("./getCustomer")

.success(function(response) {$scope.customers = response;});

 $scope.filterOptions = {
            filterText: ''
          };}
```

**Spring Mvc Controller code**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/getCustomer" , method=RequestMethod.GET)

public List<Customer> getCustomerList() throws IOException{

    List<Customer> customers= customerDao.getCustomer();
    return customers;
}
```

Comment: you'd better show us how you call REST API(your angularjs code) and the implementation of your controller. I suppose you didn't handle `@RequestMapping` well.

Answer (score 0):

You have to cancel ajax cache method while using "get"

```js
$.ajax({
    url: 'xyz.com',
    cache: false,
    type: 'GET',
    data: yourData,
    success: successfunction,
    error: errorfunction 
});
```

Or you can cancel all cache operations in  tags;

```html
<meta http-equiv="PRAGMA" content="NO-CACHE">
```

but it will not really effective while some times :)

Comment: i disabled the cache while making request but it is not working, is it any way if i click on refresh page, instead of refreshing it should prompt to some other page.?

Comment: Try to get same link with POST method